# Why is my code giving me garbage values and sometimes segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make an implementation of merge() given 2 sorted linked lists, and output a linked list that merges the two and is sorted. I first create an array and put the items there, but when I print the array elements I get garbage values/seg fault. I know it's a lot of code to go through but I'd really appreciate anyone who can help :)

```
typedef struct _node {
    int data;
    struct _node * next;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t * head;
    node_t * tail;
} LL_t;

LL_t* createList(int num_nodes);
void printList(LL_t* L);
void merge(LL_t * L, LL_t * L2);

void merge(LL_t * L, LL_t * L2){
    if(L2->head==NULL){ // empty L2
        free(L2);
        return;
    }
    else if(L->head==NULL){ // empty L1
        *L=*L2;
        free(L2);
        return;
    }

    node_t* node=L->head;
    int mid=0;
    if(node->next!=NULL){
    for (mid=0; node->next!=NULL; mid++) //finds last index of L1
        node=node->next;
    }

    L->tail->next=L2->head;
    L->tail=L2->tail;
    node_t* ind = L->head;
    free(L2);
    int len=0;
    for (len=0; ind!=NULL; len++) // finds num of items in list
        ind=ind->next;

    int arr[len];
    int newarr[len];
    node_t* cur= L->head;

    for(int i=0; cur!=NULL; i++){ // creates array with list items
        arr[i]=cur->data;
        cur=cur->next;
    }

    int first=0;
    int last=len;
    int leftpos=0;
    int rightpos=mid+1;
    int newpos=0;


    //  insert elements to arr until a half of the array
    //  reaches mid or last
    while(leftpos<=mid && rightpos<=last-1){
        if(arr[leftpos]<arr[rightpos]){
            newarr[newpos++]=arr[leftpos++];
        }
        else
            newarr[newpos++]=arr[rightpos++];
    }

    // fills in the rest of the array
    while(leftpos<=mid)
        newarr[newpos++]=arr[leftpos++];
    while(rightpos<=last)
        newarr[newpos++]=arr[leftpos++];
    for(int j=0; j<len; j++)
        printf("newarr=%d\n",newarr[j]); 

    }

int main(void){
    int num_nodes = 4;
    int num_nodes2 = 3;
    LL_t* L=createList(num_nodes);
    LL_t* L2=createList(num_nodes2);
    merge(L, L2);

}
// Creates the list. No problem here
LL_t* createList(int num_nodes){
    LL_t* L = malloc(sizeof(LL_t));
    L->head=NULL;
    L->tail=NULL;
    node_t *n;
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_nodes; i++) {
        n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
        scanf("%d",&n->data);
        n->next = NULL;
        if (L->head == NULL){
            L->head = n;
            L->tail = n;
        } 
        else {
            L->tail->next = n;
            L->tail = n;
        }
    }
    puts("\n");
    return L;
    }
```

Comment: If you're getting compilation warnings, you should fix them. If not, why did you put the compilation-errors tag?

Comment: What is the definition of `LL_t`?

Comment: Updated it @user3386109 and I removed the tag barmar

Comment: The best way to figure this out is to step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Debugging skills are essential in software development

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here in the `merge()`:

```
while(rightpos<=last)
    newarr[newpos++]=arr[leftpos++];
                         ^^^^^^^
```

Here, the condition of `while` loop is `rightpos<=last` but accessing `leftpos` index element of `arr` and incrementing it. And if `rightpos` is less than `last` then the `while` loop condition will always be `true` which makes it an infinite loop. Every iteration of `while` loop is incrementing `leftpos`, at one stage its value will be greater than the size of array `arr` and accessing the array element beyond the size of the array is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which includes program may give segmentation fault. It should be:

```
while(rightpos<=last)
    newarr[newpos++]=arr[rightpos++];
```